# Are the relative magnitudes of the learned and optimal state value function the same?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, value-functions, value-iteration

I have been reading recently about value and policy iteration. I tried to code the algorithms to understand them better and in the process I discovered something and I am not sure why is the case (or if my code is doing the right thing)

If I compute the expected value until convergence I get the following grid:

[image]

If I compute the **optimal** value with value iteration I will get the following.

[image]

As you can see, the values are different but their relative magnitude is similar, i.e. the 3rd column in the last row has the greatest value in both computations.

I believe this makes sense, as the expected value will tend to accumulate values in "promising" cells. But I assume that the first computation won't help much because it does not tell us what is the optimal policy, whereas the second, does.

Is my understanding correct?